# Compilation Qt 4.7.3 under Windows x64 with VS 2008

Tags: visual-c++, qt4, 64-bit

I tried to compilation Qt 4.7.3 under Windows x64 with VS 2008.

Step by step:

1. Start Start Menu\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008\Visual Studio Remote Tools\Visual Studio 2008 x64 Win64 Command Prompt
2. Go to C:\Qt\4.7.3\
3. Type configure
4. Type nmake.

But I have compilation error:

```
qnetworkdiskcache.cpp
c:\qt\4.7.3\include\qtcore\private\../../../src/corelib/io/qiodevice_p.h(170) :
warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss
 of data
c:\qt\4.7.3\include\qtcore\private\../../../src/corelib/io/qiodevice_p.h(170) :
warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss
 of data
c:\qt\4.7.3\include\qtcore\private\../../../src/corelib/io/qiodevice_p.h(170) :
warning C4267: 'initializing' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss
 of data
access\qnetworkrequest.cpp(997) : warning C4996: 'sscanf': This function or vari
able may be unsafe. Consider using sscanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
 _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdio.h(32
4) : see declaration of 'sscanf'
c:\Qt\4.7.3\src\network\tmp\moc\debug_shared\moc_qnetworkreplyimpl_p.cpp(99) : e
rror C2079: '_r' uses undefined class 'QSslConfiguration'
c:\Qt\4.7.3\src\network\tmp\moc\debug_shared\moc_qnetworkreplyimpl_p.cpp(99) : e
rror C3861: 'sslConfigurationImplementation': identifier not found
c:\Qt\4.7.3\src\network\tmp\moc\debug_shared\moc_qnetworkreplyimpl_p.cpp(100) :
error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'QSslConfiguration'
c:\Qt\4.7.3\src\network\tmp\moc\debug_shared\moc_qnetworkreplyimpl_p.cpp(101) :
error C3861: 'setSslConfigurationImplementation': identifier not found
c:\Qt\4.7.3\src\network\tmp\moc\debug_shared\moc_qnetworkreplyimpl_p.cpp(102) :
error C3861: 'ignoreSslErrorsImplementation': identifier not found
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\BIN\amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I used nmake /I for compilation Qt. I compiled modules, what was needed me successful.

Comment: Provide more info. What is the compilation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all modules of Qt are easily build-able in VS.  The following configure parameters have worked for people in the past:

configure.exe -platform win32-msvc2008 -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-multimedia -no-qt3support -fast

Comment: I compiled Qt 7.4.1 without any params. But I need to compile script and scripttools.